# Is there a way to show/hide an HTML element by ID

Tags: htmx

I have the following div element and would like to hide or show the entire element with a button click using htmx if possible.  Eventually, the div will include the input form to add another comment.

```
    <div id="ticket_comments_{{ comment.id }}">
        ...{{ comment.text }}...
    </div>
```

I've looked through most of the htmx documentation along with other StackOverflow questions/answers like this one [Hide HTMX search results after option is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824629/hide-htmx-search-results-after-option-is-selected). They all work on changing the inner html of the tag, and I want to show or hide the entire tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found that worked for my setup.

```
<div hx-on:click="htmx.toggleClass('#ticket_comment_list_{{ ticket.id }}', 'hidden')">
    ...
</div>
```

and this is the target element that gets shown or hidden.

```
<div id="ticket_comment_list_{{ ticket.id }}" class="hidden">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it by using htmx api method:

```
<button hx-on:click="htmx.toggleClass(htmx.find("#ticket_comments_{{ comment.id }}"), "hidden");">Click</button>
```

where `hideen` is the class name, so you need to define `.hidden` as per your needs.

---

HTMX is mostly used to handle backend req/resp. For pure DOM manipulation you can consdier using vanilla js, jquery or [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/) (htmx sister lib).

Comment: I was unable to get this method working, but I did find something else that worked.  Putting that as a direct answer to the question.

Comment: I updated the example a lil'. I missed some details, my bad. Can you try again? tx